# Как в Dart выполнить тяжелую операцию в фоне?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как в Dart выполнить тяжелую операцию в фоне?
Есть например код?

```
void main() {
  print('startApp');
  hardOperation();
  print('runApp');
}

hardOperation() {
  print("startHardOperation");
  List list = List(100000000);
  list.forEach((element) {});
  print("stopHardOperation");
}
```

Вывод:

```
I/flutter (29084): startApp 
I/flutter (29084): startHardOperation // Ждет пока переберет массив
I/flutter (29084): stopHardOperation
I/flutter (29084): runApp
```

Как выполнить например данную операцию, но при этом, что бы код после начала hardOperation() не ждал когда выполниться hardOperation и выполнялся дальше:

```
I/flutter (29084): startApp 
I/flutter (29084): startHardOperation
I/flutter (29084): runApp
I/flutter (29084): stopHardOperation
```

Пробовал по-всякому, использовал Future, async, await. Можно конечно использовать отдельный изолят, но
мне нужен доступ к массиву главного изолята. Интересует именно как сделать в главном изоляте.

Comment: flutter и dart это одно и тоже? Хмм

Comment: Flutter написан на Dart

Comment: Опишите что именно Вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для выполнение *тяжелых* задач в Android обычно переходят в фоновый поток и там выполняют работу, чтобы не блокировать основной поток и избегать ошибок ANR.

Пример задачи которая выполняется асинхронно loadData()

```
Future<void> loadData() async {
  //здесь ваш код
}
```

[**Источник - flutter.dev**](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-you-move-work-to-a-background-thread)

[Flutter. Асинхронность и параллельность (Хабр)](https://habr.com/ru/post/497278/)

**UPD для вашего примера**

```
void main() {
  print('startApp');
  Future(hardOperation).then((_) {
    print('Future is complete');
  });
  print('runApp');
}

Future<void> hardOperation() async {
  print("startHardOperation");
  List list = List(100000000);
  list.forEach((element) {});
  print("stopHardOperation");
}
```

*Результат*

```
I/flutter (18585): startApp
I/flutter (18585): runApp
I/flutter (18585): startHardOperation
I/flutter (18585): stopHardOperation
I/flutter (18585): Future is complete
```

Comment: Вот только в Вашем примере задача совсем не тяжелая. Если так запускать тяжелую операцию, то UI будет висеть до ее окончания.